# Center image inside an anchor tag, but make the extra space unclickable?

Tags: css

HTML :

```
<a href="">
  <img class="center" src="">
</a>
```

CSS :

```
.center { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

That centers the image, but the problem is any extra `white-space` around the image is also clickable. Is there a way to fix that?

(Images vary in size)

Comment: Should be able to take out display: block;  If you have to do it like that you could try display: inline-block;   ??

Comment: Why dont you just center the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could just wrap a div around it and center the that div rather than the image itself.

```
<div class="center">
  <a href="">
    <img src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

And then add a style definition for the div.

```
.center { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: There's a problem though, If I do this I'd need to set a fixed width on the outer container, but images sizes are unknown.

Answer (score 2):

The only option I see would be putting the anchor in a div (non -clickable, with the size and style of your current anchor) and sizing the anchor based on the image:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="" class="anchor">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Atumra/0jncgxkb/

Comment: I'd need to find a way to make the anchor the same size as the image for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this

```
    <a href="" class="center">
      <img  src="">
    </a>
```

Comment: but that doesn't seem to work though, I'd need to set a fixed width for the anchor tag.